# In C# how do you transform a list of records into an indefinite amount of hierarchy levels?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

We are currently receiving a list of accounts that have an optional parent account id. When ingesting the data we realized that the parent-child relationship isn't as simple as we thought. We're finding that that many of the hierarchies are 3-4 levels deep and sometimes even up to 7 levels in the hierarchy chain.

We're looking for a way to transform the source account data to an object with a list of child records, and those child records can have child records, and so on indefinitely.

```
public class AccountSourceData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class AccountTransformedData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AccountTransformedData> ChildAccounts { get; set;}
}

public List<AccountTransformedData> TransformAccountData(List<AccountSourceData> srcAccounts)
{
    List<AccountTransformedData> accounts = new List<AccountTransformedData>();
    foreach (var parentAccount in srcAccounts.Where(t => !t.ParentId.HasValue))
    {
        ....
        ..
        ....        
    }
    
    return accounts;
}
```

To clarify the resulting list of data would be a list of parent accounts. Each parent account would have child account and those child accounts could potentially have child accounts. For instance

```
parent account 1
--- child account List
-------child account 1
---------- child account List
-------child account 2 
---------- child account List
---------------grandchild account 1  
------------------ grandchild account List
parent account 2
--- child account List
-------child account 1
---------- child account List
-------child account 2
---------- child account List
---------------grandchild account 1  
------------------ grandchild account List
```

Comment: your implementation of `AccountTransformedData` seems to be correct, what problem are facing with that? Sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: What is the actual question? Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: are you trying to generate a hierarchy of the class so you can iterate through like `A.B.C.D` or what?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear - I'm trying to figure out how to loop through the flat incoming data and build a hierarchy without hardcoding loops for each level of the hierarchy. Same function should work if all accounts only have 1 parent account or if there's 100 levels of parent accounts

Comment: you declared the return type of your method as `List<AccountTransformedData>`. Is that an actual `List` what you need back, or other data structure (maybe one more convenient for hierarchical data)?

Comment: I see you updated the question to include the expected output, If you can add the input sample you are getting it will be helpful.

Comment: The incoming data is similar to AccountSourceData (without all the extra metadata). Essentially, the "parent id" can be ANY account. So a child account can have another account as its parent and that account can have another account above it, and so on

Comment: You only need a single dictionary that maps account ids to accounts. Upon processing of any line you ask the dictionary if it contains an account with id of that line's id. If it doesn't you make a new account. Then you ask the dictionary to give you the account for that line's parent id (which should exist as it will have been seen earlier) and add the tracked account for this line as a child of the tracked parent. You don't need 100 loops for 100 levels because at any moment you're dealing with just two levels in the hierarchy; this line and its parent. The dictionary knows both by that time

Comment: If your lines may be in any order you make a first pass and fill the dictionary with accounts, then you make a second pass and wire them up by asking the dictionary to retrieve you the parent for the current line and associating the current line's account with the parent's children collection (and optionally also the current line's parent with the parent account if you're tracking that way too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update based on your OP's edit:

This is one straightforward way to implement that:

```
static List<AccountTransformedData> TransformAccountData(List<AccountSourceData> srcAccs) {
  var acc = srcAccs.ToDictionary(a => a.Id, a => new AccountTransformedData { Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name, ChildAccounts = [] });
  var res = new List<AccountTransformedData>();
  foreach (var grp in srcAccs.GroupBy(a => a.ParentId, a => a.Id))
    if (grp.Key is int pid)
      foreach (var id in grp) acc[pid].ChildAccounts.Add(acc[id]);
    else
      foreach (var id in grp) res.Add(acc[id]);
  return res;
}
```

And here is some test data:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var srcAccounts = new List<AccountSourceData> { 
    new() { Id = 0, Name = "Linda" },
    new() { Id = 1, Name = "Mike", ParentId = 3 },
    new() { Id = 2, Name = "Prasana", ParentId = 3 },
    new() { Id = 3, Name = "Li", ParentId = 5 },
    new() { Id = 4, Name = "Cameron" },
    new() { Id = 5, Name = "Solange", ParentId = 4 },
    new() { Id = 6, Name = "Giovanni" },
    new() { Id = 7, Name = "Brianna", ParentId = 6 },
    new() { Id = 8, Name = "Tyson" },
    new() { Id = 9, Name = "Anna", ParentId = 8 },
    new() { Id = 10, Name = "Saul", ParentId = 1 },
    new() { Id = 11, Name = "Bob", ParentId = 4 },
    new() { Id = 12, Name = "Aldebaran", ParentId = 6 },
  };

  var transfAccounts = TransformAccountData(srcAccounts);
  foreach (var account in transfAccounts)
    Console.WriteLine(PrintAccount(account));
}

static string PrintAccount(AccountTransformedData account) => account.Name + account.ChildAccounts switch {
  [] => "", 
  [var child] => $" > {PrintAccount(child)}",
  [.. var children] => $" > [{string.Join(", ", children.Select(PrintAccount))}]"
};
```

That will output:

> Linda
> Cameron > [Solange > Li > [Mike > Saul, Prasana], Bob]
> Giovanni > [Brianna, Aldebaran]
> Tyson > Anna

Comment: I think this would work for a 2 level hierarchy where theres one parent and then one child. But what if the child has child accounts and those child accounts have more accounts and so on? I'm trying to figure out how to loop that scenario

Comment: It works for any level. Just throw in some data in there and see.

Comment: From my example above, Cameron > [Bob, Solange > [Li > [Mike > Saul, Prasana]]]

Comment: Ah I see, let me test this

Comment: I think its almost what I'm looking for. Based on the sample data you have in your example, I expected 4 records in the return list since those are the top level accounts with no parents.

Comment: Got it. Check my last edit

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public class AccountManager
    {
        public List<HierarchyData> PopulateHierarchy( List<AccountRow> dataSource)
        {
            var topLevelItems = dataSource
                .Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
                .Select(x => new HierarchyData
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    ChildAccounts = []
                }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in topLevelItems)
            {
                AddSubItems(item, dataSource);
            }

            return topLevelItems;
        }

        private static void AddSubItems(HierarchyData item, List<AccountRow> sourceData)
        {
            var children = sourceData
                .Where(x => x.ParentId == item.Id)
                .Select(x => new HierarchyData
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    ChildAccounts = []
                }).ToList();
            
            item.ChildAccounts.AddRange(children);

            //add the children recursively
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                AddSubItems(child, sourceData);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then you can simply use it like this :

```
var hierarchy = new AccountManager().PopulateHierarchy(data);
```

Comment: I think this would work for a 2 level hierarchy where theres one parent and then one child. But what if the child has child accounts and those child accounts have more accounts and so on? I'm trying to figure out how to loop that scenario

Comment: this is a recursive call on addsubitems, it will add children as long as there is children in the hierarchy....

Comment: apologies I didn't initially see the function being called recursively. this is a good solution as well but I went with Rodrigo's solution

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use a lookup table to request an account by its Id:

```
        public List<AccountTransformedData> TransformAccountData(List<AccountSourceData> srcAccounts)
        {
            List<AccountTransformedData> accounts = new();
            List<AccountTransformedData> result = new();
            
            // Populate `accounts` with Id, Name and an empty ChildAccount list
            foreach (var srcAccount in srcAccounts)
            {
                accounts.Add(new AccountTransformedData()
                {
                    Id = srcAccount.Id,
                    Name = srcAccount.Name,
                    ChildAccounts = new()
                });
            }

            // Create a lookup table to get an account by its Id
            Dictionary<int, AccountTransformedData> getAccountWithId = new(accounts.Select(a => new KeyValuePair<int, AccountTransformedData>(a.Id, a)));

            // Add each child into the ChildAccount list of it parent
            foreach (var srcAccount in srcAccounts)
            {
                if (srcAccount.ParentId.HasValue)
                {
                    // If the account has a parent, add it to the list of its parent
                    getAccountWithId[srcAccount.ParentId.Value].ChildAccounts.Add(getAccountWithId[srcAccount.Id]);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Otherwise, it is a "root account", add it to the result list
                    result.Add(getAccountWithId[srcAccount.Id]);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I think this would work for a 2 level hierarchy where theres one parent and then one child. But what if the child has child accounts and those child accounts have more accounts and so on? I'm trying to figure out how to loop that scenario